# Custom search cancel button at FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am trying to customize search cancel button at . I found 1 way, but it doesn't work on Firefox. Can I do it without js?

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    width: 15px; 
    height: 15px;
    background: #ccc; /* example style */
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<input type="search" class="search__input" placeholder="Enter text">
```

Comment: ok u want to change stying for cancel button?

Comment: @supriyasureshg no, cancel button is not shown on Firefox

Comment: add vendor prefix -moz-  in css for firefox browser.

Comment: @Buzzinga really, all browsers except Firefox and IE support this feature.
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-search-cancel-button)

Comment: @wayfqrer yes, i know. i was just answering supriyasureshg's question.

Comment: @Buzzinga; wayfqrer not saying that button is invisible so thought some prefix issue.